# Vue 3: Injected template component, printing custom input variables

Tags: vuejs3

I need to write a component that will have its template injected and this template will contain variables that will need to be compiled based on the provide/inject variables.

**The question is**: what do I need to replace the question marks in order to obtain the expected result? I'm open to other approaches as well.

PS1: I'm using provide/inject because I have more components in the three, I simplified here for the explanation's sake.

PS2: The `input_data` comes from the user's input.

PS3: Can come with more than one variable.

Application:

```js
<parent :input_data="{full_url:'{{base_url}}/some/path/here', variables:[{key:'base_url','value':'http://test.com'}]}"></parent>
```

Parent component:

```js
<script>
import Custom from './Custom.vue'
import { computed } from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'parent',
  props: ['input_data'],
  provide: () => ({
    variables: computed(() => {
        let variables = {}
        for (let v of this.input_data.variables) {
            variables[v.key] = v.value
        }
        return variables;
    })
  })
}
</script>
<template>
  <custom :template="input_data.full_url"></custom>
</template>
```

Component definition so far:

```js
export default {
  inject: ['variables'],
  props: {
    template: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
  },
  // ???
  render(){
    return this.template
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```html
<div><!-- app -->
  <div><!-- parent -->
    <div><!-- custom component -->
      http://test.com/some/path/here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working example on the [Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the expected result by returning a string in the render function:

```js
render() {
  let template = this.template
  const matches = [...template.matchAll(/\{\{([^\}]+)\}\}/g)]
  for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    if (!this.variables.hasOwnProperty(matches[i][1])) {
      continue
    }
    template = template.replaceAll(matches[i][0], this.variables[matches[i][1]])
    }
  return template
}
```